# React on render shows previous state value

Tags: reactjs, render

I'm a beginner for ReactJS, just started learning and started writing code for guessing numbers but the guess count shows different values. `{this.state.attempts}` holds the no. of attempts it took the user to find the answer to show the correct value. But `{this.state.result}` shows the result on each click but if user finds the answer it shows the previous state. I'm wondering how this happens. Is that because it's not under `render()`?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class NoLifeCycComps extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.getInitialState();
        this.checkValue = this.checkValue.bind(this);
        this.updateInput = this.updateInput.bind(this);
    }

    randNum(){
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    }

    getInitialState(){
        return {
            num: this.randNum(),
            inputValue: '',
            attempts: 0,
            result: '',
            reset : false
        }
    }

    reset() {
        this.setState(this.getInitialState());
    }

    checkValue() {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return { attempts: prevState.attempts + 1 }
        });
        if (this.state.inputValue > this.state.num) {
            this.state.result = "higher";
        } else if (this.state.inputValue < this.state.num) {
            this.state.result = "lesser";
        } else if (this.state.inputValue == this.state.num) {
            this.state.result = "you found it on " + this.state.attempts + "attempt(s)";
            this.state.reset = true;
        }
    }


    updateInput(e) {
        this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value })
    }

    render() {

        return ( 
            <div className = "numberGuess">
                <h3> Guess the number </h3>
                <input type = "text" value = { this.state.inputValue } onChange = { this.updateInput }/>

                {this.state.reset  ? <button onClick = { () => this.reset() }> start again! </button> : <button onClick = { () => this.checkValue() }> click </button>}
                No.of Attempts took: { this.state.attempts } <br/>
                <span> { this.state.result } </span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: From seeing your code, you are updating the state manually (`this.state.result = "higher";` for instance). You should use `setState()` instead.

Comment: He is using a Class component. I didn't think you could use `useState` in a Class component as it is meant for Functional components where "state" does not exist.

Comment: @CraigConover, yeah that functional components are trending a lot in recent days. At that time I didn't knew this feature exist. Started working on it in past few months. Its really great!!

Answer (score 7):

`setState` is a async function. Next statement of `setState` may not have updated state value. Also I found mutation state update in your code. Please avoid mutation update. You should update all state using `setState`

### Example

```
  checkValue() {
    let {
      attempts,
      inputValue,
      num,
      result,
      reset
    } = this.state;

    attempts++;

    if (inputValue > num) {
      result = "higher";
    } else if (inputValue < num) {
      result = "lesser";
    } else if (inputValue == num) {
      result = "you found it on " + attempts + "attempt(s)";
      reset = true;
    }

    this.setState({
      attempts,
      result,
      reset
    });
  }
```

In this example we storing existing state value in variables and doing operation on that. At the end of calculation we are updating state once.

Comment: This may help to understand mutation https://lorenstewart.me/2017/01/22/javascript-array-methods-mutating-vs-non-mutating/